# Is there a way to separate a column into multiple columns using each text-based cell as a delimiter?

Tags: excel

I am trying to build a function that will look through one column and split it into multiple columns using any text cell as the delimiter. Below is an example of what I mean by this.

I am looking for a function that will turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

I wish I could document what I have tried so far, but I don't even know where to begin or what to even search on Google to find an answer to this. I've also asked co-workers and nobody has a clue. Any help will be appreciated!

Edit: Made title more clear for others searching for a similar problem

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: Hi, I am using Excel 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would easier if you had `Office365`. Now can do but it will slower for large dataset. As per my below screenshot first put below formula in `C1` cell then drag across right to get fruits names.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$12)/ISTEXT($A$1:$A$12),COLUMN(A$1))),"")
```

To get values use following formula to `C2` cell then drag and down then right as needed.

```
=IFERROR(IF(D$1="",INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(C$1,$A$1:$A$12,0)+1&":A"&LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:$A$12<>""),ROW($A$1:$A$12))),ROW(1:1)),INDEX(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH(C$1,$A$1:$A$12,0)+1 & ":A" & MATCH(D$1,$A$1:$A$12,0)-1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harun, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a powerquery script that will do it for you. Insert>add table. Then data>from table or range. Then to go to view>advanced editor and paste in this script. Then home>close and load.

`enter code here`

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Source),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Demoted Headers", "Column1", "Column1 - Copy"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each try [Column1]/[Column1] otherwise ""),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if [Custom] <> 1 then [#"Column1 - Copy"] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Conditional Column",{"Custom.1"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Custom] = 1)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Custom", "Column1"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column1 - Copy", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Custom.1", "Fruit"}, {"Column1 - Copy", "Value"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Fruit", "Value"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Reordered Columns"),
    #"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(#"Transposed Table"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Transposed Table1", {"Column1"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Column1=text, Column2=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count],"Index",1)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom", {"Column1", "Column2", "Index"}, {"Column1.1", "Column2", "Index"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Count", "Column1.1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "Column2"),
    #"Transposed Table2" = Table.Transpose(#"Pivoted Column"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table2", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Apples", Int64.Type}, {"Bananas", Int64.Type}, {"Oranges", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here will be a little simpler formula without `INDIRECT`.

For fruits:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$12)/ISTEXT($A$1:$A$12),COLUMN(A$1))),"")
```

for numbers:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$13)/((ROW($A$1:$A$13)>LOOKUP(9^9,ROW($A$1:$A$13)/($A$1:$A$13=D$1)))*(ROW($A$1:$A$13)<LOOKUP(9^9,ROW($A$1:$A$13)/($A$1:$A$13=E$1)))),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]